# How the binding are done with decorators using Ninject?

Tags: inversion-of-control, ninject, decorator

Based on this question : [Should thoses kind of service go injected in a base class ? (versus static classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425668/should-thoses-kind-of-service-go-injected-in-a-base-class-versus-static-class/8428047#8428047).

How the binding would be done with decorators using Ninject ? or any DIContainer ?

```
public class CachedLoggedRepository : IRepository
{
   public IRepository repository { get; set; }
   void Add();
}

public class CachedRepository : IRepository
{
   public IRepository repository { get; set; }
   void Add();
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
   void Add();
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use conditional bindings e.g

```
Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>().WhenInjectedInto<CachedRopsitory>();
Bind<IRepository>().To<CachedRepository>().WhenInjectedInto<CachedLoggedRepository>();
Bind<IRepository>().To<CachedLoggedRepository>();
```

Comment: +1 And in some (much rarer) cases, you might be using a generic-based `TImpl`, in which case you `Bind<TAbstraction<>>().To<TImpl<>()` as above - in that case you use a slightly different `.When`... clause which [constrains](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) based on the base generic type of the concrete type being injected into. Another useful thing to bear in mind is that if you ever find you need something slightly different to whats needed, you get the Ninject source and find in files / static analyze through it to find examples - e.g. look at `WhenInjectedInto`

Comment: How can this be done when you want to configure multiple dependencies by convention?

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: For some reason this way didn't work for me (messy monolith application and not familiar with NInject or application; lost the will to live trying to understand it) but had to use `Rebind` like this `Rebind<IRepository>().To<CachedRepository>();` and then `Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>().WhenInjectedInto<CachedRepository>();`