# Ninject dependency injection with Decorator pattern

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, ninject, decorator

Say, I have such classes hierarchy:

```
public interface IRepository { }

public class SomeSimpleRepository : IRepository {}
```

Now I want to "decorate" SomeSimpleRepository with additional functions

```
public class MoreAdvancedRespository : IRepository 
{ 
    private readonly IRepository _originalRepository;

    public MoreAdvancedRespository(IRepository original) 
    { }
}
```

After awhile another one..

```
public class TrickyRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly IRepository _originalRepository;

    public TrickyRepository (IRepository original) 
    { }
}
```

Now, I need to accomplish binding. In application I need the instance of TrickyRepository, to be initialized with MoreAdvancedRespository. So, I need to write something like:

```
Bind<IRepository>().To<TrickyRepository>.With ??
```

Here I'm confused, I need somehow to say, take MoreAdvancedRespository but initialize it with SomeSimpleRepository. This is a kind of chain of dependencies that have to be resolved against one interface.

Does any one have suggestion on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How the binding are done with decorators using Ninject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447037/how-the-binding-are-done-with-decorators-using-ninject)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How the binding are done with decorators using Ninject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447037/how-the-binding-are-done-with-decorators-using-ninject)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `WhenInjectedInto`:

```
Bind<IRepository>().To<MoreAdvancedRespository>()
                   .WhenInjectedInto<TrickyRepository>();
Bind<IRepository>().To<SomeSimpleRepository>()
                   .WhenInjectedInto<MoreAdvancedRespository>();
```

See [this blog post](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/04/ninject-binding-and-the-decorator-pattern/) for more info.