# Ninject contextual bindinng like structuremap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container, ninject-2

Hi I am using Ninject IoC container. I can not convert the structuremap code to ninject.

**This is Structuremap code binding**

```
For<IProductCatalogService>().Use<ProductCatalogService>().Named("realProductCatalogService");
For<IProductCatalogService>().Use<CachedProductCatalogService>()
                  .Ctor<IProductCatalogService>().Is(p => p.TheInstanceNamed("realProductCatalogService"));
```

And **I am using Ninject code like this**

```
Kernel.Bind<IProductCatalogService>().To<ProductCatalogService>().Named("realProductCatalogService");
Kernel.Bind<IProductCatalogService>().To<CachedProductCatalogService>().Named("cachedProductCatalogService");
```

But this not working.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447037/how-the-binding-are-done-with-decorators-using-ninject

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you want to inject some implementation of `IProductCatalogService` into `CachedProductCatalogService`, that also implements `IProductCatalogService` and then use this cached implementation in the rest of the application as the default component.

With Ninject you can configure it using the `.WhenParentNamed` conditional binding like this:

```
Kernel.Bind<IProductCatalogService>()
      .To<ProductCatalogService>()
      .WhenParentNamed("cached");

Kernel.Bind<IProductCatalogService>()
      .To<CachedProductCatalogService>()
      .Named("cached");
```

When there is a request for `IProductCatalogService` ninject will try to resolve the conditions. If the parent component (that *asked* for the injection) is named `"cached"` (the `CachedProductCatalogService` in your case) than ninject will return `ProductCatalogService` otherwise it will return `CachedProductCatalogService` as the default.