# How to do Binding with decorators using Ninject without dependency?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, decorator, cross-cutting-concerns

I understand how to configure the decorates as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447037/how-the-binding-are-done-with-decorators-using-ninject). But I see one problem. In my case, I want avoid the dependency of the Repository.

```
Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>().WhenInjectedInto<CachedRopsitory>();
Bind<IRepository>().To<CachedRepository>().WhenInjectedInto<CachedLoggedRepository>();
Bind<IRepository>().To<CachedLoggedRepository>();
```

To elaborate, I have **UI**, **BL**(Business Layer), **DL**(Data Layer). UI and DL reference BL. The above code sits in composition root in UI. And **IRepository** sits in BL and **Repository** belongs to Data layer. I dont want to reference DL in UI. That is I dont want to make DL a dependency to UI. so the code we use in such scenario is as follows using Convention over configuration.

```
m_Kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("Northwind.*.dll").SelectAllClasses().
    BindAllInterfaces());
```

So the question is simple, **how can I use conditional bindings with convention over configuration**?

Comment: Hi Steven. Your reference helped and contains a ton of info. Exploring all the options. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [CompositionRoot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19121286/1977871)